# Proper notation of a condition

Tags: notation

Let's say that we have two different sets, $S_1,S_2$, and also that you have a combination $a=(a_1,a_2)$

Which is the proper way to notate the following:

a) something holds if  $a \in S_1$ **or** $a \in S_2$,

b) something holds if $a \in S_1$ **and at the same time** $a \notin S_2$

Comment: You define $a = (a_1, a_2)$ but that information seems to be irrelevant given the rest of the problem?

Comment: If it's of any help, we say that for any sets $S_1$ and $S_2$, that $a \in S_1 \cup S_2$ if and only if $a \in S_1$ and $a \in S_2$. We also say that $a \in S_1 \setminus S_2$ if and only if $a \in S_1$ and $a \notin S_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write

1. $a \in S_1 \cup S_2 \Rightarrow \dots$
2. $a \in S_1 \setminus S_2 \Rightarrow \dots$

although I suspect you want to express some logical combination of the conditions $a_i \in S_i$.